# Dojo key press event is not working

Tags: javascript, dojo

I am using dojo to disable other keypress events on `dojo.form.numberTextBox`.
I am doing in this way:

```html
<input style="width: 100px" data-dojo-type="dijit.form.NumberTextBox"  
  name="test" id="test" maxlength="3">
```

And using the script:

```javascript
require(["dojo/keys", "dojo/on"], 
    dojo.connect(dijit.byId("remainderDays"), "onKeyPress", function (evt) {
    var charOrCode = evt.charCode || evt.keyCode;
    if (charOrCode == keys.NUMPAD_0) {
        dojo.stopEvent(evt);
    }
}));
```

Its not working.

Even the Javascript function to disable keypress events except  numbers is not working.
But when I remove dojo type from input, it starts working.

Any idea or help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you placed the `dojo.connect` wrong and if I understood well, you're trying to block all keys except the numbers. If you want that, you should check for something like:

```
if (evt.charOrCode > '9' || evt.charOrCode < '0') {
    ...
}
```

The code itself looks like:

```
require(["dijit/form/NumberTextBox"]);
require(["dojo/ready", "dojo/parser", "dojo/on", "dojo/keys"], function(ready, parser, on, keys) {
    ready(function() {
        parser.parse();

        on(dijit.byId("test"), "keypress", function(evt) {
             if (evt.charOrCode > '9' || evt.charOrCode < '0') {
                 dojo.stopEvent(evt);
             }
        });
    });
});
```

As you can see I removed the `dojo.connect` (because it's deprecated) and I used the `"keypress"` event. I also fixed your code (because your syntax was wrong).

A working JSFiddle can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/veEgg/1/).

Comment: <script>
    require(["dojo/keys", "dojo/on"], 
         dojo.connect(dijit.byId("test"), "onKeyPress", function (evt) {
         var charOrCode = evt.charCode || evt.keyCode;
         if (charOrCode == keys.NUMPAD_0) {
             dojo.stopEvent(evt);
         }
     })); < script >
This was actually the mistake to type remainderDays instead of 'test'.

But problem is I have used dojo widgets and I do not want any key to be pressed on numberTextBox field.
Because default NumberTextBox shows error message only when any other key expect numbers is pressed.

Comment: @user2280743 I updated my answer with the code that should work :)

Comment: Works great until version 1.9.x where some performance changes were made and the `keypress` event stopped firing for all keys. You have to use the `keydown` event the `key` property instead. http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/releasenotes/1.9.html

Answer (score 1):

You can add the following line instead of using key press event:

```
var btnClick = dijit.byId("test")._onKey = function(evt) {
 key = evt.keyCode;
 if (key == dojo.keys.ENTER) {
  //what you want it to do
 }
}
```